# After install SSL some Problem with Magento 1.9.3.0

Tags: magento-1.9, login, ssl, https

after i have install SSL in webshop i get this errors

1  a user tries to login with SSL (https: //www.mydomain.com/customer/account/login/), he returns to the login page (the same) and it doesn't go on... Come back always!

If I change the base url SECURE from https to http, it works! All that with all browsers

2
- if customer click in catalog product list tries to  add to card or quick view  pop up open somewhere else

hope you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing an SSL certificate could be a hassle for store owners. If not done correctly, the issue could seriously hamper the experience of the visitors.

When working with SSL, the store owners should make sure that:

1. SSL is installed correctly
2. the secure URL is set
3. Secure URLs are
4. Implemented in the frontend and the backend

   5. The SSL certificate is Set to include www
5. No insecure links on the store

These are the solutions for some of the common SSL related issues in Magento. I hope that you are able to apply the fixes yourself without any issues. Visit: [http://magenticians.com/magento-ssl-configuration-issues-resolved/ and resolve your problem.](http://magenticians.com/magento-ssl-configuration-issues-resolved/)

Comment: ok " T h A N K "  for link i will try .. hope

Comment: no work i have try all but no result